# How can I move a file to internal App from Document/Inbox in Swift like "try FileManager.default.moveItem"?

Tags: ios, swift, file

I would like to move a file to internal App from Document/Inbox.
I already write below. But something is wrong.

---

```
class FileListViewController: UITableViewController {
```

---

```
class func move(_ atPathName: String, name: String, toPathName: String) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: atPathName, toPath: toPathName)
    } catch {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVRMpath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/Inbox/(indexPath.row)"
    let newVRMpath:String? = Bundle.main.path( forResource: "Febboy2", ofType: "vrm" )
    let selectedNameinList = newarray[indexPath.row]

    FileListViewController.move(selectedVRMpath, name: selectedNameinList, toPathName: newVRMpath)
```

---

Error Message:

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

---

.vrm file is around 10MB

Finally I use a file in ViewController. I need to move a file to inside of project from Documents/Inbox.
If I misunderstand this solution pls give me a advise.
I couldn't use a VRM file directly to select URL Documents/Inbox in a other class.

### ---

Thanks for the hint from reply I changed the code like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let selectedVRMpath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/Inbox/(indexPath.row)"
   guard let newVRMpath:String = Bundle.main.path( forResource: "Febboy2", ofType: "vrm" ) else { return }
   let selectedNameinList = newarray[indexPath.row]
   print("Selected! \(self.newarray[indexPath.row])")
   FileListViewController.move(selectedVRMpath, name: selectedNameinList, toPathName: newVRMpath)
}
```

---

Error message was disappear. But i know there is problem yet.

Comment: 1. Don't make `newVRMPath` optional. 2. Your code for `selectedVRNpath` is wrong. Never build a path in such a way. 3. This code will never work on a real iOS device. An app's bundle is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force-unwrap `newVRMpath` or use `guard`

```
guard let newVRMpath = Bundle.main.path( forResource: "Febboy2", ofType: "vrm" ) else { return }
FileListViewController.move(selectedVRMpath, name: selectedNameinList, toPathName: newVRMpath!)
```

This will fix the compile error but won't work as you can't write to main bundle , you need to create that new path  say from documents folder

Comment: FYI - this ignores the other 2 glaring problems with the code.

Comment: thanks. When I wrote like this I could build. But there is error message.

Comment: Selected! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.vrm
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-06-16 00:56:56.781203+0900 xxxxxx[2360:729097] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.

Comment: Are you sure there is a content inside `let selectedVRMpath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/Inbox/(indexPath.row)"` ?? also note it's not recommeded to use `NSHomeDirectory`